# FFMPEG convert audio track to mono and pan full right / left

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

How would one convert a stereo track to mono (So the data from both channels is meshed) and then pan the mono'ed track 100% either right or left using FFMPEG? (I may have to convert it back to stereo to do this?)

This may sound a little crazy but the reason I want to do this is because I am working on an audio experiment where I want to take a track, cut out all the lows and then boost the super highs / air and then put it to one side (left channel) then do the same with a little bit different settings and then pan that fully to the other side (right channel) Then I will take the same original track and boost the lows a little but keep it center and then mesh all 3 using ffmpeg merge feature, creating possibly an "enhanced" stereo widened version of the track.

Basically I want to know how to pan a track 100% to the left or to the right using ffmpeg

According to the [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pan-1) this will convert it to mono with a bigger factor to the left channel: (I am not sure how you would make it pan 100% to the left or to the right)

```
pan=1c|c0=0.9*c0+0.1*c1
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Mono is a single channel: there is no left and right. When you downmix stereo to mono it is already "full" by default.

Comment: Hey LongNeckbeard, I am trying to take a stereo track, and make it mono so the data that was on both the left and right sides is meshed. Then after that take the mono track and pan it fully to one side. (I then will also do this to the other side but with a little bit of effects added) I am doing this because I am working on a stereo widening experiment where I cut out the lows boost the highs then pan tha 100%t to each side, then mesh it with the same track with the medium and lows centered. Kind of a custom / crazy formula for enhancing a track.

Comment: I know how to do all the other stuff, I have just never used ffmpeg's panning feature and dont know how to pan a track 100% to the left or right, also i feel like if I were to just pan it fully to the left or the right without converting it to mono first I would loose the data from the other side. I hope that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
pan=stereo | FL < c0 + c1
```

No need to go to the stereo -> mono -> stereo route. The above pan statement keeps the output as stereo and sets the Front Left channel as the sum of the input first and second channels (the `<` tells pan to rescale the sum so clipping is avoided. Use `=` if that's not a concern). Front Right is not specified, hence it is muted.